# What's the best companion for a unneutered male guinea pig?

Tags: guinea-pigs

I have a five-year-old unneutered male guinea pig. He recently lost his companion. He was very healthy, but probably too old to be neutered. What's the best companion for him? I'm thinking about adopting a neutered male or a spayed female.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was actually "un-spayed female guinea pig" :) But you did not tell us anything about his now-lost companion.

Comment: @virolino ... then they get children, this is not a good advice...

Comment: @Allerleirauh: I am aware of that, but OP did not provide enough info for a good answer. That is why (kind of) asked for clarifications. Maybe OP wants to start a business with guinea pigs? Let's wait for their answer.

Comment: @Allerleirauh: chill, friend, I do not take offense for something that is reasonable and makes sense ;)

Comment: Hi, I'm not a breeder. I don't want guinea pigs babies. I had two guinea pigs, both male, unneutered. Then one of them got a bladder stone and the vests suggested putting him down. We did that and it was very painful. Now I have only one unneutered male guinea pig, five years old, very healthy and energetic.

Comment: if you decide to not neuter him, then you have only two options: unneutered male or neutered female... maybe you look in a shelter, who needs a new home :) because the 5 year old should not get a baby as companion